# Drawing a particular part of flowchart in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This might be simple, but looks like a daunting task to me. The following is a portion of my flowchart roughly drawn in google drawing. The bubbles (actually dots) indicate that there is a continuation of frames.  [image] How do I draw this in tikz? The choice of blue color for the block shapes was arbitrary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please try to include a MWE no matter how simple it is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
%
%
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw] (topnode) at (3,2) {Node A};
\node[draw] (botnode) at (3,-2) {Node B};
\foreach\x in {1,...,5}{
\node[draw,trapezium,trapezium left angle=120, trapezium right angle=60pt] (innernode\x)at (\x,0) {\x};
\draw (innernode\x) |- ($(innernode\x)!0.5!(topnode)$) -| (topnode);
\draw (innernode\x) |- ($(innernode\x)!0.5!(botnode)$) -| (botnode);
}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

There are many options here; I used the `matrix`. I also didn't elaborate to much on the code below. For example, if you need to calculate the intersections between lines, you must use the `intersections` library. You can also look in the PGF manual, it has lots of examples.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{mathtools,ellipsis}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    any/.style={%
        draw,
        shape=trapezium,
        trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120pt,
        fill=blue!50,
        minimum size=0.5cm,
        },
    topper/.style={%
        any,
        shape=rectangle,
        },
]

\matrix (somematrix) [%
    matrix of nodes,
    nodes=any,
    column sep=0.5cm,
    row sep=0.5cm,
    ]
{%
& |[topper] (n1)| Node A & & \\
|(n2)| Frame 1 & |(n3)| Frame 2 & |[draw=none,fill=none]| $\cdots$ & |(n4)| Frame N \\
& |[topper](n5)| Node B & & \\
};

\draw (n1) -- (n3) -- (n5)
      (n2) |- ++(0,0.5) -| (n4)
      (n2) |- ++(0,-0.5) -| (n4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is " | [topper] (n1) | Node A " same as "\node [topper] (n1) {Node A}; " ??

Comment: Also could you explain "(n2) |- ++(0,0.5) -| (n4)" ?? I am not getting that "++" part.

Comment: @dineshdileep regarding your first question: yes, it is the same. But since I said `matrix of nodes` in the matrix options I can avoid always saying `\node`. For the second question, it works as the following: takes node named n2, goes up (x=0, y=0.5), then goes right, and finally goes down to meet the n4 node. The explanation of `|-`, `-|`, `--`, `++` can be easily found in the PGF manual.

Answer (score 6):

After some fiddling around, I got my own code working (am the questioner)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
%
%

\tikzset{
block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
  text width=5em, text centered, minimum height=4em},
data/.style = {draw,trapezium,trapezium left angle=70,trapezium right angle=-70,minimum height=3em,fill=blue!20}  
}
%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node [block] (nodeA) {Node A};
\node [below of=nodeA] (spreadout) {}; 
\matrix[
            row sep=0.3cm,column sep=0.5cm, below of=spreadout] (framematrix) {
        \node[data] (frame1){ Frame 1};&
        \node[data] (frame2){ Frame 2};&
        \node (dots1) {$\ldots$};&
        \node (dots1) {$\ldots$};&
        \node (dots1) {$\ldots$};&
        \node[data] (frameN){ Frame N};\\        
        };
\node [below of=framematrix] (spreadin) {};
\node [block,below of=spreadin] (nodeB) {nodeB};

\path [draw] (nodeA) --(spreadout);
\path [draw] (spreadout.north) -| (frame1);
\path [draw] (spreadout.north) -| (frame2);
\path [draw] (spreadout.north) -| (frameN);
\path [draw] (frame1) |- (spreadin.north);
\path [draw] (frame2) |- (spreadin.north);
\path [draw] (frameN) |- (spreadin.north);
\path [draw] (spreadin.north) -- (nodeB);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```